# Force execution of shell expressions stored in file?

Tags: bash, shell

Let's say I have hi.json:

```
{
  "word": "$(echo hello-world)"
}
```

Is there an easy way to force the shell expression executions such that my result would be?

```
{
  "word": "hello-world"
}
```

One way I can approach it is to store the contents of this string within some shell file such that I have something like:

```
scratch_MAIN() {
  content="{\"word\": \"$(echo hello-world)\"}"
  echo $content
}

scratch_MAIN
```

that gives me the output of

```
{"word": "hello-world"}
```

However, I would like to store the hi.json content in a separate file away from shell file. Is that possible?

Comment: not sure if you also have other requirements but as a general solution you can take a look at [tag:jinja2].

Answer (score 0):

`eval` shall do your the job. You have to explicitly escape quotation marks or they will be processed when json content passed to `eval`.

My test `hi.json`:

```
{
  "word": "$(echo hello-world)",
  "foo": 123,
  "boolean": false,
  "files": "$(ls)"
}
```

If you have json processor like `jq`, you can also pretty print the result.

```
$ fc=$(cat hi.json) && eval echo ${fc//\"/\\\"}
{ "word": "hello-world", "foo": 123, "boolean": false, "files": "hi.json testfile.sh" }

$ fc=$(cat hi.json) && eval echo ${fc//\"/\\\"} | jq
{
  "word": "hello-world",
  "foo": 123,
  "boolean": false,
  "files": "hi.json test.sh"
}
```

Comment: This will work for simple cases, but have trouble in a variety of more complex situations. For example, if you have an item like `"ultimatequestion": "6 * 9"`, it'll replace the `*` with a list of filenames in the current directory (even though there's no shell command there at all). It'll also get confused by many shell commands contains quotes and/or escapes). I think that to do this right, you really need to parse the JSON, and only apply expansion to the strings within that; leaving the shell and JSON syntaxes mixed just makes a mess.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend not doing this but...

```bash
result=$(eval "cat <<EOD"$'\n'"$(<hi.json)"$'\n'EOD)
```

Note that the result of substitution may not be legal inside a json string. For example, newlines in command output will need to be escaped.